# Slideshow-like application

Tags: android, android-layout, slideshow, android-animation

I'm supposed to make a simple android application, in fact it's almost as simple as a slideshow.

The good thing is that the content of each slide is very similar - some text and a photo. So I only have to do one layout and simply switch it's content on a slide motion or a button press.

I think it would be more appealing if I add some suitable animation - e.g. flipping the whole page.

Is there already a tool for this? If there's not than what's the best/simplest way to do this?

Comment: Have you googled it before posting it here?

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/